# Highcharts custom indicator does not affect y axis range after zoom

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've built a custom indicator that I'm using together with other series. When I zoom, the custom indicator series is clipped when it goes above/below the other series data ranges. The data range of the visible custom indicator series does not affect the y axis range.

Am I missing something in the custom indicator implementation or configuration? Is it a bug? Do I have to handle the y axis range manually on zoom?

All built-in indicators affect the y axis range on zoom, I expect custom indicators to do the same.

Here's an example, a slight modification of one of the the official highcharts custom indicator demos. I'm subtracting 25 from the indicators y-value to offset it from the scatter plot series. Try the jsfiddle link to reproduce the bug.

```
function getLinearRegression(xData, yData) {
    var sumX = 0,
        sumY = 0,
        sumXY = 0,
        sumX2 = 0,
        linearData = [],
        linearXData = [],
        linearYData = [],
        n = xData.length,
        alpha, beta, i, x, y;

    // Get sums:
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x = xData[i];
        y = yData[i];
        sumX += x;
        sumY += y;
        sumXY += x * y;
        sumX2 += x * x;
    }

    // Get slope and offset:
    alpha = (n * sumXY - sumX * sumY) / (n * sumX2 - sumX * sumX);
    if (isNaN(alpha)) {
        alpha = 0;
    }
    beta = (sumY - alpha * sumX) / n;

    // Calculate linear regression:
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x = xData[i];
        y = alpha * x + beta;

        // Prepare arrays required for getValues() method
        linearData[i] = [x, y - 20];
        linearXData[i] = x;
        linearYData[i] = y;
    }

    return {
        xData: linearXData,
        yData: linearYData,
        values: linearData
    };
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oloflandahl/r0tvkbje/1/

Zoom in the left part of the chart, approximately 145-155 on the x axis.
The indicators are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a bug.

The problem which you are struggling to is that zoom changes the yAxis range - for example: for x range from 145 to 150 points y values are in range 45-50, meanwhile, the regression value for this range is ~30, but zoom has changed the yAxis range from 44 - 54.

I think that the easiest solution is setting the yAxis.min to some value, like 25 for the shared demo.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o3618wmc/

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Weight (kg)'
    },
    min: 25
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.min

---

Unless you want to recalculate and show the regression line for actually displaying range - it will require a different solution.

Confirm if setting yAxis.min is a right solution for your case or you will need more help this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I want the y axis range to be dynamic, independent of what data I use. If I use another dataset that renders the regression below 25 it will still be clipped. I expected that the y axis range would adjust to custom indicators automatically just like for built-in indicators, but it seems I'll have to implement a workaround.

Comment: Ok, so I have another conception. Use the getLinearRegression function to get data and render it as a line series and add it after the initial load by using the events.load feature. The visual output is the same and it is work as you expect with zoom. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uqg17zcn/ let me know what you think

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept that as a workaround solution, although I still think it's a bug that a custom indicator doesn't affect the y axis range on zoom.

Comment: If you want you can report this problem on Highcharts Github issue channel where core developers will respond with their opinion about this. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues